# Is the induction cooktop sinking my eggs? Why are they sticking to the bottom

Tags: eggs, oil, induction, breakfast

I have this tried and true fried egg recipe I have done multitudes of time. It is as simple as putting in a pool of some oil and cracking the eggs into it. I can then cover it and leave it to cook for awhile for some great results.

I just started at a new place that has an induction cooktop and I have been having the hardest time doing this recipe! Essentially now every time I try the eggs tend to somehow start sticking to the bottom. This has never happened to me before.

This is probably a ridiculous question but is there anything about induction cookware that might encourage eggs to stick to the bottom or otherwise not float too well?

Answer (score 2):

It is simply a different rate of heating. Your pan is getting hotter than you are accustomed to. You'll have to experiment with settings, and possibly pans, to find one that works.

Comment: So if I start it on a very low setting that might prevent the eggs from sticking?

Comment: You have to do it on the right setting. Eggs are very sensitive that way. You might want to start observing your eggs and learning to recognize by sight when the temperature is right, and after that determine the setting at which to do the "set and forget" thing, else your recipe will only ever work on one stove and pan combination. With the induction, I would start the experimentation erring on the side of too low, because it frequently gets pans much hotter even on low settings. That|s why a well conducting pan will help. If you cannot get it low enough, consider placing the pan on a trivet.